# exporting array data to excel - getting date in ###### format and number in 6.7628E+11 in php

Tags: php, arrays, export-to-excel

I am exporting array data to excel - and getting date format changed in ###### format and number like 676280454445 changes to 6.7628E+11 in php.

Comment: How are you exporting to Excel? As a CSV file? As HTML? As a native format BIFF or OfficeOpenXML file?

Comment: Note that `#######` isn't a format.... it's what MS Excel displays when data is too wide for the column; extend the column width to show all the data and it will magically display your date

Comment: And `6.7628E+11` is scientific format, which MS Excel uses for numbers large numbers; if you're using  native Excel format file, then set a number format mask like `#0` to display the full value without that chnge; otherwise you can't do much because MS Excel will always do that when importing non-native file formats

Answer (score 0):

Convert date in to mm/dd/yyyy format then export in excel

Comment: Isn't `#######` Excels' way to say _"The content is too wide for the cell"_? I believe widening your cell in Excel (just drag it) exposes the number.